# How to call sp_executeSql with a Table Value Parameter (TVP) from within a Powershell script using Invoke-Sqlcmd?

Tags: t-sql, powershell

So, I know how to call `sp_executeSql` with a TVP from a C# code. Which means I can do it in Powershell with ADO.Net.

But I am curious how to do it with `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command? The problem is that the TVP values are given by the user and I want to avoid any possibility for the Sql Injection.

I currently have the following code:

```
$ControlSql = @"
SELECT ClientId,Namespace,DatabaseConnectionString
FROM Namespace n
JOIN DatabaseConnection dc ON n.DatabaseConnectionId = dc.DatabaseConnectionId
WHERE Namespace IN (SELECT Value FROM @Namespaces)
"@
$ControlParams = "'@Namespaces dbo.TableOfString READONLY'"
$ControlQuery = "EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt = $ControlSql, @params = $ControlParams, @Namespaces = $Namespaces;"
```

The `@Namespaces = $Namespaces` part is, of course, wrong. `$Namespaces` is a list of user provided values. I have no idea how to populate the `@Namespaces` TVP from it.

Well I do, but I wonder if it is the right way. I can generate individual `INSERT INTO @Namespaces ...` statements per each and every value from `$Namespaces` before passing the latter to the final `SELECT` query.

So if `$Namespaces` contains 1,000 entries the resulting sql is going to contain 1,000 parameters.

Is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a CSV file delimited by comma containing  the values and  use bulk insert to fill the Table Value Parameter (TVP )
The Sql code is:

```
 BULK INSERT @Namespaces 
 FROM 'path_to_Namespaces.txt'  
  WITH   
  (  
     FIELDTERMINATOR =' ,',  
     ROWTERMINATOR =' \n'  
  );
```

Modify your code to pass the filename  (insted of passing TVP)
In this way, you avoid passing  large size of parameter.

Comment: Too problematic - the sql server needs to have access to the file. That means setting up the share to be visible by all the relevant servers.

Comment: Shares can be secured per user and invisible to others if the relevant servers are working within a Domain, have a look: 
https://thesqldude.com/2011/12/30/how-to-sql-server-bulk-insert-with-constrained-delegation-access-is-denied/

Comment: Surely they can. But it creates a configuration overhead. There must be an easier way and I think I have found a way - I should use a `DataTable` instead of TVP.

Comment: But I am still at loss how to pass it using Invoke-SqlCmd. Looks like if I want to avoid any additional configuration I need to resort to ADO.NET invoked from the script.

Comment: That is right. DataTable is compliant with TVP and can be passed to the script using Ado.net SqlCmd class. Invoke-Sqlcmd.doesn't support user defined data type like TVP or DataTable.